# Why is this being printed?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to make a program that creates a singly linked list that takes input and then prints out the values in the linked list. Below is the function that is supposed to print out the values.

```
void Linked_list_return()
{
    Node* pointy;
    pointy = h;
    cout << pointy -> data;
}
```

but instead of returning the values it prints out 0 instead. I don't know what's wrong below is the full program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void Linked_list(int input_data, int &decision);
void Linked_list_return();
Node* h;

int main()
{
    int size_of;
    int input;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter? " << '\n';
    cin >> size_of;
    cout << "What are the numbers?" << endl;
    while (size_of > 0)
    {
        cin >> input;
        Linked_list (input, size_of);
        size_of--;
    }
    cout <<  "Completed!" << endl;
    Linked_list_return();
    return 0;
}

void Linked_list(int input_data, int &decision)
{
    Node* n;
    Node* t;

    n = new Node();
    t = new Node();
    h = new Node();
    t->data = input_data;
    t->next = n;
    t = n;

    if (decision == 0)
    {
        n = new Node();
        t-> data = input_data;
        t -> next = NULL;
    }
}

void Linked_list_return()
{
    Node* pointy;
    pointy = h;
    cout << pointy -> data;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentations.

Comment: And those would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h = new Node;`
So it is new object, meaning instantiated.
And you do 
`pointy = h;`.
So `pointy->data` will be 0.

Comment: Why doesn't it change after user input.

Comment: You never set any value to `h->data`. You added data to t->data but did not connect it to the head pointer. `h` at all which has both its members uninitialized.

Comment: in `void Linked_list(int input_data, int &decision)` If (decision == 0) you create an additional node `n` which is not used and causes a memory leak of the previous contents of `n`

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning anything to h first, it’s empty